# node.js native binding slower than php native extension

Tags: node.js, node-modules, node-gyp

Hello i am currently trying to port a php-extension (native C) to a node.js native extensions.

i am using nan ->https://github.com/rvagg/nan - for api abstraction

i have the following node cpp code:

```
NAN_METHOD(Core::getInfo) {
   NanScope();
   int somevar=1;
   Local<Object> return_obj = NanNew<Object>();
   return_obj->Set(NanNew<v8::String>("int"),NanNew<v8::Integer>(somevar));
   return_obj->Set(NanNew<v8::String>("version"),NanNew<v8::String>("teststr"));
   NanReturnValue(return_obj);
}
```

and the following php-extension c code:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(core_get_info) {
   int somevar;
   if (array_init(return_value) == FAILURE) {
      RETURN_FALSE;
   }
   add_assoc_long(return_value, "int", somevar);
   add_assoc_string(return_value, "version", "teststr", 1);
}
```

when running the call to this function in 1000000 iterations the NODE variation is MUCH Slower.

test.php

```
for($x=0; $x<1000000; $x++) {
    $i = core_get_info();
}
var_dump($i);
```

test.js

```
var x=0;
var i;
for(x=0; x<1000000; x++) {
    i=core.getInfo();

}
console.log(i);
```

the factor seems to be about 170% slower in node than in php - has any one a tipp what i am doing fundamentally wrong in the node part.

edit: node version v0.11.14

Comment: why do you presume something is fundamentally wrong? Try moving the time-consuming part (a huge loop) to the native code and I think you'll find the there's not that much difference. It's probably more work needed for the JS interop than the PHP one, and that's why calling into C++ from JS takes longer than from PHP. I would expect it to be honest.

Comment: the huge loop is just for demonstration/testing - to be able to compare the performance between the php-ext and node-ext - this huge loop isnt going into a production code - and therefore moving the loop into C++ code is not an option.

actually it seems to be the obj->Set() wich is slow! and so i thought maybe i am missusing the c++ interface or somewhat - i cant believe that 170% is for real

Comment: one thing you can easily do to help some is to cache the object key names (`int` and `version` and even `teststr`, since version number wouldn't change during the life of the process) so that they are only created once and then reused.

Comment: you should also mention what version of node you're using.

Comment: thx - edited the post and added the node version v0.11.14

caching the value keys - isnt' possible because in the real-world code there would be dynamic values - testsr - just for demonstration.

caching the object sounds interesting - any samples? - i think thats one of the parts php's `add_assoc_*` functions actually do.

Comment: Converting data from C structs to javascript objects (which are actually C structs as well) or back again is known to be expensive. As much as possible use the V8 specific structs to avoid the conversion. It is for this reason that it is even possible to write pure js code in node that is faster than C. There are two examples I know of - one an sql driver another a json parser - where the pure javascript code ends up faster than C.